# mongoose in C how to listen to all ports

Tags: c++, c, mongoose

I try to use the mongoose to test httpserver, now I want it to listen to all ports, I try to set 0000 but failed . So I want to know how to set the port number .
Thanks !

Comment: the mongoose project is  [here](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose)

Comment: You can't listen to *all* ports. It is not supported by underlying protocol.

Comment: You want to listen from different origin. set config bind to 0.0.0.0